# NodeJS & Mongoose - Stripping out code in a CRUD module doesn't get invoked

Tags: node.js, mongoose, module

Coming from a JAVA background, callbacks can be still confusing for me.

Anyway, I have a simple Mongoose User Schema and I can create new users with the following code in the router.js

```
app.post('/signup', function(req, res){

  var newUser = new User(req.body);

  newUser.save(function(err){
    if(err) res.send(err);

    res.json(req.body);
  });
});
```

Would it be nice if I could create a CRUD module (crudUser.js) for all user operations. Something like that:

```
var User = require('../dbmodels/userDBModel');

var _this = {};

_this.createUser = function(req, res) {

  var newUser = new User(req.body);

  newUser.save(function(err){
    if(err) res.send(err);

    res.json(req.body);
  });
};

module.exports = _this;
```

and then just call this in the router.js instead:

```
var crudUser = require('../crud/crudUser.js');

app.post('/signup', crudUser.createUser);
```

but unfortunately the code in crudUser.js doesn't get invoked.

Does that work at all?

Thanks

Comment: As you have it written the actual function name is `createUser` and not `crudUser`. Is this a typo only, or the reason it's not being called?

Comment: Sorry guys, you were too fast in replying. I found the typo and correct it in the same time you posted the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should set file name without Uppercase **crudUser.js** to **cruduser.js** then try change like this.

```
var User = require('../dbmodels/userDBModel');

exports.createUser = function(req, res) {

    var newUser = new User(req.body);

    newUser.save(function(err){
        if(err) res.send(err);

        res.json(req.body);
    });
};
```

Comment: So can you tell me why **`_this = {}; _this.function(){}; module.exports = _this`** doesn't work but **`exports.createUser = function() {}`** does? Isn't that exactly the same? In my example I declare an object first, add a function to it and then publish the function, while in your example you publish the object in one go.